# "In entgegengesetzter Richtung gehen" vs. "In die entgegengesetzte Richtung gehen"

Tags: difference

Die beiden Varianten habe ich mehrmals in verschiedenen Texten angetroffen, aber bis jetzt kann ich nicht verstehen, wodurch sie sich voneinander unterscheiden (wenn überhaupt).

Comment: Wer sagt, dass sie sich voneinander unterscheiden?

Answer (score 7):

Der Unterschied ist relativ fein. Grundsätzlich bezeichnen lokale Präpositionen mit dem Akkusativ aber immer eine Richtung, während der Dativ eher einen Ort beschreibt, an dem etwas stattfindet.

Im Falle von *in* hieße das, dass *in entgegengesetzte Richtung gehen* den Fokus auf das Ziel legt, während bei *in entgegengesetzter Richtung gehen* der Fokus nur auf der Richtung liegt, in welcher momentan gegangen wird.

Der Unterschied ist allerdings so fein, dass sich beim Sprechen kaum jemand Gedanken darüber machen wird und beide Varianten quasi gleichbedeutend sind.

Answer (score 1):

Wohin? In die entgegengesetzte Richting gehen.(Akkusativ)

Wo? Er befindet sich in der entgegengesetzter Richtung. (Dativ).
*In die* wird nicht mit Dativ benutzt, deshalb ist die erste Variante falsch. Aber bin kein großer Deutschsprachenkenner, womöglich lieg ich falsch.